# Getting NEW posts from a subreddit in JSON

Tags: api, reddit

How would I go about getting the **new** posts of a subreddit in JSON? Just tacking on .json to the url (http://www.reddit.com/r/SOME_SUBREDDIT/new.json) returns the following:

```
{
    kind: "Listing"
    -
    data: {
        modhash: ""
        children: [ ]
        after: null
        before: null
    }
}
```

The children array doesn't contain any posts. I've come to find that http://www.reddit.com/r/SOME_SUBREDDIT/new actually routes to **new?sort=rising** when what I need is **new?sort=new**.

and **/new?sort=new.json** of course wont work.

Comment: How we get the list of subscribe subreddits using reddit api in android?

Comment: How to call this link https://www.reddit.com/subreddits/mine/ in android

Answer (score 75, accepted):

The `.json` modifier should be put at the end of the path component, not the entire URL. The URL you're looking for is:

```
http://www.reddit.com/r/subreddit/new.json?sort=new
```

Comment: Where Do i look for a list of all available json modifiers for Reddit ?

Comment: @NeilWilliams Can I ask where you saw that? While it works, as far as I know the docs say all calls require OAuth, and nowhere do I see this particular usage documented?

Comment: We'd definitely recommend and prefer you use OAuth these days. The URL structure described above is no different on OAuth though.

Comment: You can also add `&limit=100` to get some more posts, but that's the limit of the limit

Comment: How to get list of subreddits/mysubreddits subscribe by user ?

Comment: @1j01 +1 for "the limit of the limit"

Answer (score 9):

If you are interested in getting a realtime stream of all of the Reddit new post, Pusher has an unofficial Realtime Reddit API. You can read more about it on this blog post http://blog.pusher.com/pusher-realtime-reddit-api/.

But it basically you do nifty things like. It's also available in Ruby, Python, PHP, etc.

```
<!-- Include the Pusher JavaScript library -->
<script src="http://js.pusher.com/2.2/pusher.min.js"></script>

<script>
  // Open a Pusher connection to the Realtime Reddit API
  var pusher = new Pusher("50ed18dd967b455393ed");

  // Subscribe to the /r/AskReddit subreddit (lowercase)
  var subredditChannel = pusher.subscribe("askreddit");

  // Listen for new stories
  subredditChannel.bind("new-listing", function(listing) {
    // Output listing to the browser console
    console.log(listing);
  };
</script>
```

Disclaimer: I work for Pusher

Comment: Apparently I was trying this ( got from Pusher blog ) , I can see it's executing 

subredditChannel.bind('pusher:subscription_succeeded', function(data) {
 console.log("Subscribed");
});
But after that no return from "subredditChannel.bind("new-listing",callback)".  Why so ? can you help me with this ?

Comment: How to get list of subreddits/mysubreddits subscribe by user ?

Comment: This seems not to work anymore. After fixing the syntax error in the code, I see no errors and I see it doing what seems like long polling. All of the polls come back with 204 No Content, though, while various new posts were submitted to askreddit. The `console.log(listing)` is never triggered.

Comment: Yea. Seems like this public channel is down now. You have to create your own backend for this to work.